# Toggle button always show false state_checked icon

Tags: android, togglebutton

i'm trying to create a custom toggle button to show one icon when its true and another when it state is false.

I created a custom selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_chart_bar_svg" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_chart_line_svg" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

and using like this:

```
<com.example.widgets.chart.layouts.ChartToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/chartToggleButton"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/m"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/m"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/periodFilter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

and my ToggleButton class looks like this:

```
class ChartToggleButton @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatToggleButton(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    init {
        background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.bg_chart_toggle)
    }
}
```

stated_check = false looks like this

[image: stated_check = false]

and with stated_checked=true the image that I was using as false still showing bellow the right one:

[image]

Testing in an emulator with API 29 (Android Q)